# Should I edit this answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Link to question: [Sort command not working as intended on numbers](https://askubuntu.com/q/874385/582858)

> [image: screenshot of answer]

The answer given does indeed answer the question suitably and in my opinion deserves to be accepted. However I feel the comment that has been posted on the answer adds value to the answer and should be included.

Is it good form to take the comment and add it into the answer, or is it best just left as it is?

It is my understanding that comments should be treated as exactly that, comments, and the deleting of any comment should never affect the quality of the question or answer it is in response to. To that end I'd support appending it to the answer itself, but as I don't consider myself very experienced here I wanted to confirm before stepping on any virtual toes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would say no since it would be quite a huge change to the answer itself.

You can though ping the OP of the answer to add the information into the answer and why the OP should and upvote the comment to show that it was useful. Upvote comments will appear even if there are tons of comments and some of them have to be cut off into the 'Show More Comments' part.

In summary, ping the OP telling the user why the information should be added to the answer and upvote the comment since you're supposed to upvote comments that add value to the post it is under.

Comment: Bizarrely the comment has now been deleted. But I've commented on the answer so will leave it in OP's capable hands

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should ask this on the site's meta, since they are the experts on the subject.

Generally I would say that you can suggest an edit to clarify that word, however the chances are that it gets rejected because actually the user posting the answer should do that. He also read the comment and didn't think of it worthy enough to edit it in his answer, so that is enough for me to be a little hesitant to editing it.

Comment: I considered asking on the site meta but I felt it was a general enough question as to be relevant for most sites on the network